# In Windows, Can i determine if there is a internet connectivity on a specific adapter

Tags: windows, networking, adapter

Is there any way to determine that internet connection exists on a specific adapter...this includes not just the presence of an IP address, but an actual verified connectivity.

Ex. Something like InternetCheckConnection on a Wifi adapter

Comment: Windows 7+ has the information in _Network and Sharing Center_ but it is not obvious the means to access.  Certainly there is a large question of relevance as such a concept bypasses the routing table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is within the [Microsoft Windows Network List Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The article provides an example whereby `pNetwork` is a specification of a particular network that you are interested in:

```
NLM_CONNECTIVITY nlmConnectivity;
hr = pNetwork->GetConnectivity(&nlmConnectivity);
if (nlmConnectivity & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET)
{
// "IPv4 internet connectivity";
}
if (nlmConnectivity & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_INTERNET)
{
// "IPv6 internet connectivity";
}
```